# Special characters causing problems when compiling LESS

Tags: css, compilation, less, special-characters

Has anyone had issues with LESS compiling CSS that utilizes plus signs [+] and/or greater than [>] symbols, whereas the inclusion of these causes compilation errors/fails? (we're using the standard lessc compiler). The LESS below is identical to what we're trying to compile - the first plus after banana.keynote is what sets the compiler error off:

```
.banana.keynote {
    + {
        label:before {
            border: 2px solid #CC6633 !important;
        }
    }
}
.banana.chunga {
    + {
        label:before {
            border: 2px solid #ffb5ff !important;
        }
    }
}
.banana.gordita {
    + {
        label:before {
            border: 2px solid #4067ea !important;
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: admittedly, I'm using an online converter to go from CSS to LESS - could this be producing weird artifacts in code?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe.  What are you compiling? What errors do you get?

Comment: Compiling something like this:
'.banana + label {position: relative;}'
gives a **ParseError: Unrecognized input in _filename_** message in PowerShell.

Comment: Post more code around this statement (the statement itself is correct but something else before/after it may make compiler to fail). Also you really need to put the code into you question and not into comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#combinators) in Less must always be followed by an element identifier, i.e. you can't use `+` alone on its own. Rewrite your code to:

```
.banana.keynote {
    + label:before {
        border: 2px solid #CC6633;
    }
}
```

If you really need to get it "alone" for some reason you may hack it through selector interpolaton:

```
@plus: ~'+';

.banana.keynote {
    @{plus} {
        label:before {
            border: 2px solid #CC6633;
        }
    }
}
```

### ---

P.S. Additionally note that the following code:

```
.banana.keynote + {
    label:before {
        border: 2px solid #CC6633;
    }
}
```

while compiled w/o any errors, does not produce the proper CSS (invalid `+` is just silently omitted).